# How can dataframe with list of lists can be explode each line as columns - pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame as below

```
--------------------+
|                pas1|
+--------------------+
|[[[[H, 5, 16, 201...|
|[, 1956-09-22, AD...|
|[, 1961-03-19, AD...|
|[, 1962-02-09, AD...|
+--------------------+
```

want to extract few columns from each row from above 4 rows and create a dataframe like below . Column names should be from the schema not hard coded ones like column1 & column2.

```
---------|-----------+
| gender | givenName |
+--------|-----------+
|      a |       b   |
|      a |       b   |
|      a |       b   |
|      a |       b   |
+--------------------+

pas1 - schema
root
|-- pas1: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- contactList: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- contact: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- contactTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- contactMediumTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- contactTypeID: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- lastUpdateTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- contactInformation: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- dateOfBirth: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- farePassengerTypeCode: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- gender: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- givenName: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- groupDepositIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- infantIndicator: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- lastUpdateTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- passengerFOPList: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- passengerFOP: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- fopID: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- lastUpdateTimestamp: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- fopFreeText: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |-- fopSupplementaryInfoList: struct (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |-- fopSupplementaryInfo: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
|    |    |    |    |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi @darla, welcome to Stack Overflow! I ask you to elaborate a little bit your question. What do you mean for "not hardcoded"? You maybe want to flatten the dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract few columns from a dataframe containing structs, you can simply do something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession,Row
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([Row(pas1=Row(gender='a', givenName='b'))]).toDF()

df.select('pas1.gender','pas1.givenName').show()
```

Instead, if you want to flatten your dataframe, this question should help you: [How to unwrap nested Struct column into multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913258/how-to-unwrap-nested-struct-column-into-multiple-columns)