# Convert missing string values to isNull in Pyspark

Tags: string, pyspark, null, nan

I am quite new to pyspark and I have a dataset which I load from a csv (in Glue). There is one column `code` where there are `string` and `long`.

```
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="db", table_name="data_csv")
df.printSchema()

root
|-- code: choice
|    |-- long
|    |-- string
```

and it seems that pyspark sees the missing values as `string`. I found this by flattening the column like [How to unwrap nested Struct column into multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913258/how-to-unwrap-nested-struct-column-into-multiple-columns).

```
df_flattened.show()

+---------+------+
|     long|string|
+---------+------+
|  9965213|  null|
|300870254|  null|
|  5607653|  null|
|  5798154|  null|
|   389954|  null|
|      572|  null|
|   951091|  null|
```

I actually want the whole column to be `string` but I could not find how to make the `null` values (above) actual `null` values that show when using `isnan`. Also when I try to cast the whole column into `string` and I find that none of the rows is `== 'null'`.

```
df = (df
          .toDF()
          .withColumn('code', f.col('code').cast("string"))
     )

df.select('code').where(f.col('code') == 'null').count()

0
```

What type are these `null` values and how can I convert them to "true" `null` values (that are recognized by `isNull()`)?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with null values in pyspark, you can filter them by using isnull function or replace then by using na.
Ex:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df.select([f.count(f.when(f.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
#This will give you count of null values in each of your column
```

If you want to replace null values with some other value you can use

```
df.na.fill(yourValue)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but why do i get bigint for all of my columns with the above code?

Comment: It's because you are letting spark inferring the schema for you and there might be some bigint values....you can explicitly pass schema to overcome this use StructType to create your own schema and pass it to the df.